# Keras image classification val_accuracy doesn't improve

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, classification

I tried to basically copy this tutorial: https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/

But I can't seem to improve on my val_accuracy score. I also have 2 kinds of images dogs (Hunde) and cats (Katzen) but only 95 samples each. I have an "upper" folder "Hunde und Katzen" where the folders of these samples are. I probably have to tune some parameters, because my sample size is so low but I already tried at some code parts.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import os

num_skipped = 0
for folder_name in ("Hund", "Katze"):
    folder_path = os.path.join("Hund und Katze", folder_name)
    for fname in os.listdir(folder_path):
        fpath = os.path.join(folder_path, fname)
        try:
            fobj = open(fpath, "rb")
            is_jfif = tf.compat.as_bytes("JFIF") in fobj.peek(10)
        finally:
            fobj.close()

        if not is_jfif:
            num_skipped += 1
            # Delete corrupted image
            os.remove(fpath)

print("Deleted %d images" % num_skipped)
image_size = (180, 180)
batch_size = 16

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "Hund und Katze",
    validation_split=0.5,
    subset="training",
    seed=9,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "Hund und Katze",
    validation_split=0.5,
    subset="validation",
    seed=9,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
#Found 190 files belonging to 2 classes.
#Using 95 files for training.
#Found 190 files belonging to 2 classes.
#Using 95 files for validation.

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    ]
)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=8)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=8)

def make_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Image augmentation block
    x = data_augmentation(inputs)

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    for size in [128, 256, 512, 728]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(size, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(size, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(size, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    x = layers.SeparableConv2D(1024, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    if num_classes == 2:
        activation = "sigmoid"
        units = 1
    else:
        activation = "softmax"
        units = num_classes

    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


model = make_model(input_shape=image_size + (3,), num_classes=2)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
#('You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at 
#https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) ', 'for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.')
epochs = 10
    
    callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("save_at_{epoch}.h5"),
    ]
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    model.fit(
        train_ds, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=val_ds,
    )

Output: Epoch 1/10
6/6 [==============================] - 8s 1s/step - loss: 0.7691 - accuracy: 0.6421 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_accuracy: 0.4632
E:\anacondaBI\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py:1410: CustomMaskWarning: Custom mask layers require a config and must override get_config. When loading, the custom mask layer must be passed to the custom_objects argument.
  layer_config = serialize_layer_fn(layer)
Epoch 2/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 995ms/step - loss: 0.7747 - accuracy: 0.6526 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 3/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 0.6991 - accuracy: 0.7053 - val_loss: 0.6905 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 4/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 0.5411 - accuracy: 0.7368 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 5/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 0.3949 - accuracy: 0.8316 - val_loss: 0.7023 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 6/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 0.4440 - accuracy: 0.8526 - val_loss: 0.7199 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 7/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 0.3515 - accuracy: 0.8842 - val_loss: 0.7470 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 8/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 0.3249 - accuracy: 0.8526 - val_loss: 0.7955 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 9/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 994ms/step - loss: 0.3953 - accuracy: 0.8421 - val_loss: 0.8570 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
Epoch 10/10
6/6 [==============================] - 6s 989ms/step - loss: 0.4363 - accuracy: 0.7789 - val_loss: 0.9189 - val_accuracy: 0.5368
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x2176ec764c0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

95 samples for each class is less to achieve a decent accuracy

1. decrease your **validation_split to 0.05 (5% for validation )**, as you have very less number of data points
2. If the first step does not help you then you can use **transfer learning** i.e using architectures that have a good accuracy on imagenet for e.g: **MobileNets**, **ResNets** and **efficientnets**
3. If the above 2 steps are not giving you a good accuracy then try **increasing your data size** and tune your hyperparameters.

Comment: yeah the code works just fine with 2500 samples for each class, ty :)